# Graphical user interface to change data capture on Oracle

Tags: oracle, change-data-capture

I'm learning how to implement change data capture in Oracle. However, not being a DB specialist but rather a developer, I find the process tedious with respect to other things that I have to do. I end up doing it because my DBA/DevOp don't want to take care of it.

Hence I was wondering if there is any tool that can help set up Oracle change data capture. In other words a simple graphical user interface that would write the all code for me. Creation of change table, PL/SQL script, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate post in [StackOverflow](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87015/graphical-user-interface-to-change-data-capture-on-oracle).

[Oracle 11.1 Documentation Warning:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16579/cdc.htm) "Oracle Change Data Capture will be de-supported in a future release of Oracle Database and will be replaced with Oracle GoldenGate. Therefore, Oracle strongly recommends that you use Oracle GoldenGate for new applications."

Attunity, the company I work for, offers [REPLICATE](http://www.attunity.com/products/attunity-replicate), a sleek GUI alternative.

hth,
Hein.